# allow_url_fopen disabled on server

Tags: php, symfony

My problem is that "allow_url_fopen" is enabled on phpinfo() [see here allow_url_fopen is ON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbRqK.png) 
but using this function i see that it's disabled [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgsRf.png)

 that's my **tt.php** :

```
<?php
$a = ini_get('allow_url_open');
if ($a == true)
    echo 'allow_url_open is ON';
else
    echo 'allow_url_open is OFF';
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You tested for `allow_url_open`, not `allow_url_fopen`. Therefore, `ini_get` will return `FALSE`.

Also, have a look at [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php). It returns a string (`"1"` or `"0"`), and only the boolean `FALSE` if that option does not exist.